# How can Maz have Luke's lightsaber in Star Wars VII?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back* we see Darth Vader cut Luke's right hand that is holding the lightsaber, and both fall down in the abyss.

In fact, in *Star Wars: Return of the Jedi* the lightsaber that Luke uses is a his own creation (we can see Darth Vader congratulate him for the job when he takes the lightsaber on Endor).

So, how can Maz have the lightsaber in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*?

Comment: We don't know yet, and I assume we won't until Episode VIII or even Episode IX.

Comment: "A good question, for another time." - Maz Kanata

Answer (score 9):

Maz answers this question by stating that it is a tale that will be told at another time.

While the current canon has yet to clarify through books or other media how Anakin/Luke’s lightsaber found its way from the depths of Cloud City’s underbelly to Maz Kanata's castle, the character is slated to appear in *Star Wars: Episode VIII* in May 2017. It is more than likely that she will describe what happened to it in the next episode.

Comment: Is it for sure the Cloud City one?  Or could it be the new one Luke created?  I forget what colors they all were.

Comment: It's the one that Luke lost in Cloud City for sure. That blue one with the distinct handle design was constructed by Anakin before Revenge of the Sith, then was retrieved by Obi-Wan after his defeat. It was passed along to Luke in A New Hope.

Comment: Did this ever get answered?

Comment: @BradyGilg It's only very partially been answered; Luke went searching for it shortly after his defeat at Bespin. Nobody could locate the lightsaber, so he opted to leave and help Leia, as she was in danger. Shortly after, an Ugnaught located it. That's as far as the lore has been developed.